# Multiple dynamic markings under one note

Tags: lilypond

I am working with Lilypond and can't figure out how to place two dynamic markings under a whole note.  I want it to start piano and then become forte but I don't want to use a crescendo.  I'd also rather not indicate two tied half notes. Just *p* then *f* under a whole note. This is common in older notation which I am typesetting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example in the [Notation Reference](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-attached-to-notes.html#dynamics), where it says: "Spacer rests are needed to engrave multiple marks on one note."
If you adapt it to your case, you might write:

```
\version "2.18.2"
{
  R1 |
  << f'1\p { s1\f } >> |
}
```

However, this triggers the following warning:

```
warning: Two simultaneous absolute-dynamic events, junking this one
```

and  only the first dynamic mark is printed.
So you must place the second dynamic mark on a different musical moment:

```
\version "2.18.2"
{
  R1 |
  << f'1\p { s4. s16\f s s2 } >> |
}
```

Comment: Great! Please upvote it by clicking on the up arrow in the answer. Edit: I see that it's been marked already as answer (green tick); forget my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can add one single markup that contains multiple elements to a single note:

```
\version "2.18.2"
{
   f'1 _\markup { \dynamic { f p } }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That is very efficient!

Comment: This solution also helped me with a similar problem.  I couldn't get Lilypond to engrave a \p dynamic.  (\f \pp etc al worked fine.)  I presume it's a bug or I'm missing something very obvious.  c4 _\markup { \dynamic { p } } solved it for me.